# How to determine the INTERSECT of a "projection" of row headers and column headers

Tags: excel, vba

In an excel spreadsheet, I have reference to a range of Row Headers, and Column Headers; the data corresponding to these would be the intersection of the "projection" of the two ranges. ie: the ranges themselves don't actually intersect, but projecting them down/to the right would produce the intersection I am interested in.  I am looking to determine the range representing the entire intersection of the RowHeaders and ColumnHeaders.

Looks like this:

```
   c  c  c  c  c 
r  d  d  d  d  d  
r  d  d  d  d  d  
r  d  d  d  d  d  
r  d  d  d  d  d
```

So, I start with the 2 ranges containing 'rs and c's, I am interested in deriving the range containing d's.  There can possible be some empty rows or columns after the row or header (ie: data might not immediately start in the first cell below a column header....there may be several blank rows before the first row header & data begins.

This seemed like it should work, but no such luck:

```
Intersect(rngRowHeaders.Rows, rngColumnHeaders.Columns).Address
```

Comment: So, given the ranges A2:D2  and B3:B11  - you would like this method to return  C3:E11 ? If so, I would skip the built-in excel function, get the actual row/column numbers for your two ranges, do the math on those and then transform the result to an Excel range.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you have and what your desired result should be? Are you looking, for example, on which address the 3rd column intersects the 4th row?

Comment: CaBieberach: See clarification in question.

Comment: Charles Williams already gave you the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intersect(rngRowHeaders.EntireRow, rngColumnHeaders.EntireColumn).Address
```

That should get you what you want.

Comment: I had left a comment earlier about the rows and columns being backwards, but it was just me being backwards...I think @Charles above has it backwards as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try Resize. something like this assuming that rowhdr is a named range referring to the rs and columnhdr is a named range referring to the cs. Works for me

```
 MsgBox Range("rowhdr").Offset(0, 1).Resize(, Range("columnhdr").Columns.Count).Address
```

Comment: I have tested this using named ranges as above in the edited post and it works for me: why does it not work for you?

Comment: I think it's right except that what you're calling 'rowhdr' @tbone is calling the column headers, etc. I did the same thing and left a comment for @Dick that I deleted when I realized it.